Can anyone explain to me SCM_RIGHTS in openbsd-7.5?
I was tasked with an assignment to implement something similar to SCM_RIGHTS in openbsd-7.5. My understanding is that SCM_RIGHTS isn't really a block of code, its more of a macro that is used with cmsg_type. So I was wondering that, if I had to implement something similar to SCM_RIGHTS, what file(s) would I look at in the kernel? Where should I start my code? What file(s) do I have to modify?
Thank you for the help!

Don't you have more to go on than "something similar to SCM_RIGHTS"? That should be supplementary, itself.  You need a description of the actual required behavior, and if this is at someone else's behest then it's altogether unreasonable for them to expect you to figure out what they want.

To be even more direct, SCM_RIGHTS is a macro that expands to an int value that is significant as the type code of an ancillary message on a UNIX-domain socket.  SCM_RIGHTS has no particular behavior of its own, but there are semantics associated with ancillary messages of that type. It is altogether unclear what it might mean to implement something like those semantics that is different from just using the existing feature.

SCM_RIGHTS is a macro, like PDF is three letters, but if someone asked you to make an operating system display PDFs, you wouldn't start by looking at the three letters.

@user20574 Does this mean that if I want to implement something similar, I shouldnt look at SCM_RIGHTS?

It means you should look at the whole feature instead of just the macro that activates the feature

You can start with sys/kern/uipc_usrreq.c, here are two method you need to pay attention to. first unp_internalize, which will convert the fd to the file pointer, and unp_externalize method will convert the file pointer to fd, and assign new fd if aviliable. To complete the comp3301 a2, it's necessary for you to implement similar func to associate the memory block message which you send to the kernel struct, and map it for the receiver.
